# Hacer campos dinamicos obligatorios JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo,

Lo que quiero hacer es campos obligatorios:

```
 <input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total" class="F2_GSA"><br/>


        $('.F2_GSA').each(function() {
            nombres_Campos[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
            console.log(nombres_Campos);

        });
```

Quiero capturar los value y si alguno esta vacio, se detenga el script y muestre un alerta

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Me alegro que hayas solucionado tu duda, sin embargo, consejo, no dupliques el atributo `id`, debe ser único

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto puedes validar que los campos no esten vacios y tambien señalar cual

**UPDATE**

He modificado el código para que te muestre un alert con cual ID es el que esta vació

```js
$('#Check').on('click',function(){
  $('.F2_GSA').each(function() {            
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert("El id "+$(this).attr('id')+" esta vacio");
        $(this).css('border','1px red solid')
    }else{
        $(this).css('border','1px black solid')
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total1" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total2" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total3" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total4" class="F2_GSA"><br/> 
<input type="text"  name="Total"  id = "Total5" class="F2_GSA"><br/>
<button id="Check">Revisar</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto Amigo, muchas gracias

Comment: El id es único por cada elemento en el DOM. La sugerencia es no usar el mismo para todos los input.